# Removing the selected LI from a UL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove the selected item who class has "selected" but instead of just deleting the LI item, the entire list is being cleared out. I am using jQuery for this.

I've put together a quick fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6QvvC/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script> 
<head>

<style type="text/css">
* {
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: Segoe UI;

}
#refdocs {
    border: 0;
    padding: 2px;
}
#box1 {
    border: 1px solid rgb(170,170,170);
    width: 200px;
}
#box2 {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(170,170,170);
}
#container {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#list1 {
    width: 100%;
}
#list1 ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#list1 li {
    cursor: default;
    padding: 2px;
}
.selected {
    background: rgb(228,228,228);
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {

refresh_list()

}

function remove_selected_item() {

    if ( $('#list1 ul li').hasClass("selected") ) {

        alert("yup")
        $('#list1 ul li').remove()  
    }
    else {
        alert("nope")
    }
}


function refresh_list() {

    $('#list1 ul li').click(function () {
        $('#list1 ul li').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        document.getElementById('refdocs').value = $(this).text()

    });

}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="box1">
<div id="box2"><input type="text" id="refdocs"></div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="list1">
        <ul>
          <li>Coffee</li>
          <li>Tea</li>
          <li>Milk</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="delete" onclick="remove_selected_item()">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Fiddle doesn't work in FF or Chrome for me...

Comment: You need to select the `No wrap - in <body>` option from the second dropdown on the left. Otherwise the script is wrapped in a function.

Comment: Alternatively, define the function as `window.remove_selected_item=function(){...};` to expose the function globally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function can be simplified:

```
function remove_selected_item() {
    $('#list1 ul li.selected').remove()
}
```

You need to removed selected item - so you select the `li` with class `.selected` and just remove it.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6QvvC/3/

Comment: Or optimised with ID first: `$('#list1').find('ul li.selected').remove()`

Comment: @Martijn It's interesting question, I'm actually not sure if it's going to be more optimal. Let me make a perf test..

Comment: It will use `document.getElementById` and then anyway DOM traversal for `ul li.selected`. Or it will use `querySelector` only once. Working on a jsperf test..

Comment: Ok, so I was right: my version seems to be faster. The best though is `$('#list1 .selected').remove()`. `$('#list1').find('ul li.selected').remove()` is significantly slower. At least in Chrome: http://jsperf.com/css-selector-vs-split-expression

Comment: Confirmed. Real time save is in the refresh_list function: `$('#list1 ul li').click(function () { var $this = $(this); $this.parent().find('li').removeClass('selected').end().end().addClass('selected'); document.getElementById('refdocs').value = $this.text(); });`

Comment: I stand corrected. Really thought it was faster, the whole expression surprises me, a lot of selectors it has to match. I love benchmarks like this :)

Comment: Haha, if I just take `$('#list1').find('.selected').remove()`, thats the fastest one. I changed your perf: http://jsperf.com/css-selector-vs-split-expression/3

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery selector `#list1 ul li` matches ALL `li` elements inside an `ul` inside an element with id `list1`.
`hasClass` returns true if ANY of the matched elements contains the given class.
`remove` removes all matched elements, which in the given case is all list elements. That is why the list is cleared.

Maybe dive into the power of jQuery selectors a bit: http://codylindley.com/jqueryselectors/
You can not only select elements based on their type or ID, but also on their class, their attributes, their position in the DOM (parents, siblings, children) and their state (e.g. hover).

When installing click handlers on list elements, the event delegation pattern is also pretty useful: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ It might help you to get a better understanding of how events and handler installation work with jQuery. It at least was some kind of revelation for me.